# Inicio/Fim do Horario de Verao: problema com verificação de data do tipo "maior que"

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Todo ano tenho dois problemas, um quando começa o horario de verão e outro quando acaba.

Enfim, ontem o relogio foi atrasado em uma hora isso criou um problema gigante.

A página deve permitir o usuário acessa-la somente com um intervalo de tempo, neste caso de 10 minutos.

Para isso é feito o seguinte:

Imagine:

```
<?

// $data = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$data = '2016-02-20 23:50:00';

$mysqli->query("SELECT null FROM tabela WHERE Data >= '$data' AND User = '1")

if($mysqli->num_rows <= 0){

$dataProxima = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+10 minutes");

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO tabela VALUES (0, '$dataProxima', '1')");
// Isso irá permitir que o usuário somente entre na página depois de 10 minutos.


echo 'ok';
// Pagina é carregada

}else{

// echo 'falhou';

header('location: meusite.com');
exit;   

}

?>
```

Na tabela existe:

```
id | Data                 | User
1  | 2016-02-20 23:39:00  | 1
```

Neste exemplo irá retornar:

```
ok
```

Em tese se não existir nenhuma data maior que a data atual irá continuar, se não irá falhar.

Mas...

Quando acaba o horario de verão irá automaticamente voltar ao `2016-02-20 23:00:00`, com isso irá falhar, mesmo que em tese tenha já superado a data.

Agora, depois do horario de versão, a informação será:

```
$data = '2016-02-20 23:00:00';
// Irá retornar: falhou
```

Existe alguma correção que pode ser feita diretamente para corrigir essas situações?

Ainda tem um problema maior!

Se o dado do banco for:

```
id | Data
1  | 2016-02-21 00:01:00
```

Terá que esperar novamente uma hora para retornar "ok", ao invés de um minuto.

Tem alguma função do MySQL que compense essa diferença de horario de verão usando `DATETIME`?

Comment: Sim, esse é o problema. Mas, não consigo achar uma solução para que isso não ocorra. A única solução, que consigo pensar, seria não usar nunca o horario de verão e então informar visualmente ao usuário baseado no horario de versão, ou não, quando necessário.

Comment: Não bastaria incrementar ou diminuir 1 hora? Exemplo, entrou horário de verão, decremente 1 hora no momento da comparação, porém mantém as datas e horários originais ignorando o horário de verão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta usar GMT em vez de hora local:

```
$dataProxima = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s' ...
```

De acordo com a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.gmdate.php):

> gmdate — Formata uma data/hora GMT/CUT
>   Idêntica a função date() exceto que o tempo está em Greenwich Mean Time (GMT).

Se fosse meu o código, eu não usaria nem data, usaria *[UNIX Timestamp](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.time.php)*, e faria a comparação em inteiros:

```
$tempoFuturo = time() + 600;
```

Esta solução é muito mais simples, e evita ambiguidades. Como o resultado do `time()` é um valor em segundos, somamos 600 segundos para dar um intervalo de 10 minutos. De quebra, evitamos as operações de *string* × data no DB. Comparações com inteiros são mais eficientes.